# What's the best way to get a 200 GB database from ec2 instance into RDS Postgresql by using Replication....?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

we currently run our Production database on Postgres on an EC2 instance. We'd like to migrate RDS now, but I'm unable to get the data into an RDS instance in a timely manner. Using pg_dump to get the data out, it takes me 20 minutes to create a dump file, but nearly 18 hours to (psql) restore it into my RDS instance. And during those 18 hours, my Production database has added some more data that needs to be migrated over.
While I can deal with SOME downtime (upto an hour), I can't have Production down for 18 hours! Is there a better way to do this? Say, do the restore offline and then bring the restored RDS instance into a Master-Slave combination with my current database server? Or, do a snapshot of my current database volume[my current database version is 9.0.4] and just mount that on the RDS instance?
**NOTE**:- Amazon RDS PostgreSQL Server does not allow direct host access to a DB instance via Telnet or Secure Shell (SSH)

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup log shipping from old to new server.

   Use `pg_basebackup` to create a clone of a database on new server while Postgres on old server is running.

   Start new server.

   Wait some time until new server processes logs shipped during backup.

   Disable connections to old server.

   `SELECT pg_switch_xlog()` on old server to force switching of log file as ship it to new.

   Wait some time until new server processes this last log file.

   Stop old server and promote new.

Comment: Hi Tometzky,Thanks for reply, But i just need to know it is applicable for rds postgresql server because Amazon RDS PostgreSQL Server does not allow direct host access to a DB instance via Telnet or Secure Shell (SSH),   Amazon RDS postgres engine does not offer an admin user role,rdsadmin is the superuser Amazon's own user that is used by Amazon to perform updates, run backups and do other maintenance tasks & also we don't have a permission to edit configuration file For eg:- postgresql.conf.

Comment: I see. Then trigger based replication engines like Slony or Bucardo should work.